# i18n.exists is not a function while testing via jest / react-testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using react testing library along with Jest. I am not able to mock exists function in test script.

Below is my code.

errorComponent.js

```
    import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
    
     export default function Error(props) {
      
       const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

       return (
        <div>
         {i18n.exists(props.errorText) ? t(props.errorText) : props.errorText}
        </div>
       )
     }
```

myComponent.js

```
     import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
    
     export default function Error(props) {
       
       return (
        <div>
         <Input value="" id="testig-input"/>
         <Error
            errorText={'XYZ'}
          />
        </div>
       )
     }
```

myTestFile.test.js

```
       const temp= document.querySelector(`input[id='testig-input']`);
       fireEvent.change(temp, { target: { value: '' } });
```

When I try to execute this I am getting error saying that "i18n.exists is not a function". I tried to mock but its not working. Anyone kindly help me to remove this.

Comment: Are you using the i18n provider in your tests to add the context?

Comment: No. I am not sure how to do

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you should have an `<I18nextProvider>` wrapping everything being translated somewhere. When you run the jest test, you need to render the component wrapped in the same way:

```
render(
  <I18nextProvider i18n={myConfig}>
    <MyComponent />
  </I18nextProvider>
)
```

Alternatively, can try to mock the `exists` function, but it is better to more closely mimic how your app is actually run.

```js
import * as i18next from "react-i18next";

jest.spyOn(118next, 'useTranslation').mockReturnValue({
  t: (val) => val,
  i18n: { exists: () => true }
})
```

Comment: This is not working. Can you help me with detail example.